Time Series Forecasting Feature Engineering
I've performed feature engineering and modeling my data about daily retail store sales to do time series forecasting. I tried some scenarios of features that I use for modeling. One scenario that gave me the best result is the scenario with the feature I called Number of Bulk Transactions and Number of Transactions.
Number of Bulk Transactions is a feature that shows how many bulk transactions occur in a day. A bulk transaction is when the transaction quantity meets the threshold of bulk that I set. The Number of Transactions is a feature that indicates how many transactions of a product happen on that day. Feature Number of Bulk Transaction and Number of Transaction is obtained from column Qty or quantity of product sold.
Models that use both features on modeling give the best result on forecasting if I check from the MAE, RMSE, and the visualization between actual and predicted.
But the thing is, the Number of Bulk Transaction and Number of Transactions is obtained from Qty, whereas the target column for modeling is Qty. Of course, I still can use that feature when forecasting for Test data, but what if I want to forecast to the future because those two features are obtained from Qty while the target column is Qty? Is there any recommendation? Thank you
For information, I already create some feature below:

Time Series Feature (Day, Day of Week, Month, Year)
Lag Qty (Lag 1, Lag 7, Lag 30, Lag 365)
Flag Feature (Holiday, Store Closed, No Sales, Weekend)


It's not surprising that these two features give you a good fit, because they are probably very highly correlated with the actual quantity sold, which you are predicting. However, as you are finding out, this may not be worth a lot, because in order to forecast out, you will need future values of these features (or lagged versions if you use these in your model).
And exactly because your features are probably highly correlated to your outcome, forecasting the features is likely not a lot easier than directly forecasting the quantity sold in the first place. I am not saying this is impossible, just that it likely will be quite hard.
In any case, I would very much encourage you to do a proper holdout test which simulates your actual production forecasting process as closely as possible. In-sample fit is never a reliable guide to out-of-sample accuracy.
Aside, I hope you are not coding months as dummy features. This yields ecologically nonsensical jumps and plateaus. Much better to use some periodic transforms of day of year, as per here.

Thank you for your answer
